# the best practices get version API by Mobile app version

Tags: api, design-patterns, version-control, version

I write application for ios and Android with WEB API (.NET), i use rest conception , API has versioning by url like
api/v1/Student , api/v2/Student etc... , different versions of mobile application will use different api and probably mobile app can use some version of api (one method from first version, second from other version). I write class for get data from api, with input parametr version, next I'm going to create repositories with methods getAll,getById,Delete etc...
How i can determine necessary version in repository? are there any patterns for it?

Answer (score 0):

the versioning of your API is one thing, and how the repositories (or any other business logic for that matter) is something else.

If I understand correctly, what you need to make sure is that you have backward compatibility in your API.

so if v1 returned to the client a response of structure A1, and v2 would return structure A2, you'd want the repository/business logic to return the complete set of data, and have the controller format it as A1 or A2 according to the version it supports.

in the rare cases where v2 breaks everything in v1 and there is no way around it, you're probably better of writing a separate set of class in v2, and maintain v1 separately until you cut off support for it and all clients migrate to v2. that means that you will have 2 sets of repositories, one in a namespace for v1 and one in v2 (or any other way to separate them - different class names, different solution/project etc.)